# An experiment about relativistic effect on weight

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy

[image]

The draw explains everything. However I could not understand following:

1. At the right side, since 2 masses move, the total mechanical energy is bigger(since potentials are the same, and kinetic is bigger on right) but how it causes the weight difference?
2. Can we use "relativistic mass" concept? If we can, yes I can understand the experiment. If no, how energy difference causes weight difference?

Comment: Yes. They us the notion of relativistic mass. Otherwise, there is no reason that c appears in the denominator.

Comment: Anyway you can look at the following link for why defining mass in this way is "bad": https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376

Comment: Ari, the rotating system will have more mass even without "relativistic mass", because the mass of a system can be larger or smaller than the mass of the parts (a fact that comes up in relativity whether or not you use "relativistic mass").